# Using Values from Lists in an equation/loop

Tags: python

I have a short list with coordinates: (0|0) (10|0) (10|10) (0|10). Im trying to use these coordinates to calculate the area of the square they build. 
for loop should run 4 times and perfom the math written below.
when running i get the following error in the area = .... line:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
list = [[0,10,10,0],[0,0,10,10]]

def gaussarea(coords):
    area = 0
    for coords in coords:
        area = area + (coords[0][0] - coords[0][1]) * (coords[1][0]+coords[1][1])
    return area

a = (gaussarea(list))
```

Comment: Your variable names make this needlessly confusing.  Could you write out the first two lines of arithmetic so we can see what you're trying to do?  eg `area = area + (0 - 0) * (10 + 0)`

Comment: you're variable name `list` is conflicting with the `built-in` type [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the index of an `int`, which is meaningless, since each `coords` is a list, not a nested list.

Assuming you get a rectangle (or square) for sure, you are good enough with

```
def gaussarea(coords):
    area = (coords[0][1] - coords[0][0]) * (coord[1][2] - coords[1][1])
    return area
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of `cords[0]` is an int. Therefore `cords[0][0]` is trying to index into an int, hence your error. You can remove the for loop and your code should work.